# How to delete a stubborn Atari Partition Table and create GPT?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I am installing a brand new out of the box 8TB Seagate HDD on a Ubuntu 20.04 system. I would like the partition table to be GPT and create a single ext4 partition.

In the GNOME Disk editor it claims that the partition table is of type "atari," and gparted shows it as an unrecognized label, and so neither will create a partition.

I have attempted to format the disk through the GNOME disk editor, which results in an error message: `Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)`.

I have attempted to use gparted, but it shows the disk having an unrecognized disk label even after attempting to write a GPT or MSDOS partition table, it gives the warning `/dev/sda: unrecognised disk label`

I have tried using parted with `sudo parted /dev/sda`, `select /dev/sda` (with `/dev/sda` being the correct device) and `mktable gpt` with no seeming effect.

`print` in parted gives the following output:

```
(parted) select /dev/sda                                                  
Using /dev/sda
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA ST8000DM004-2CX1 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sda: 8002GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
```

Using `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` prints:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
```

Which I followed up by using the options `o` and then `w`. Following that up with another call to gdisk results in the same output as above.

I also tried using `sudo wipefs -af /dev/sda`, which prints:

```
/dev/sda: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001c6 (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sda: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001d2 (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sda: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001de (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sda: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001ea (atari): ff ff ff ff
```

But running `sudo wipefs /dev/sda` after prints:

```
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE  UUID LABEL
sda    0x1c6  atari      
sda    0x1d2  atari      
sda    0x1de  atari      
sda    0x1ea  atari
```

Finally, I also tried:
`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress`
which ran for several hours and printed:

```
8001550286848 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 56075 s, 143 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device
7630886+0 records in
7630885+0 records out
8001563222016 bytes (8.0 TB, 7.3 TiB) copied, 56088.2 s, 143 MB/
```

I thought it might be the disk itself, but then opened another brand new 4TB Seagate Drive, and am having the exact same issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

EDIT: Initializing the Disk and partitioning it on a different system seems to circumvent the problems I was having, but am still not sure why the original system cannot consume the disk correctly. Putting the partitioned disk in the original system and placing a few text files on it works for a few hours, but overnight an `ls` on the mount point in `/media/` results in the message `ls: reading directory '.': Bad message`

Comment: So you have zeroed the entire disk. Try looking at it using a hex editor. Is it all zeroes? If not, something is terribly wrong.

Comment: Opening the disk wxHexEditor shows's all F's through the 524280 offset, and then zeros through the 67108856 offset, and then F's through the 67112952 offset, and then seems to alternate from there. So obviously something went wrong in the ```dd``` command, but I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Actually, I did run some of these other commands again to get their output, which is probably why there are F's in certain places. Ill run ```dd``` again and verify in the hexeditor that it's all zeros

Comment: Zeroing the first 100 MB should be enough.

Comment: Ran ```sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=409600 status=progress``` and got output:
```190603776 bytes (191 MB, 182 MiB) copied, 7 s, 27.2 MB/s
409600+0 records in
409600+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 8.708 s, 24.1 MB/s```
hexeditor is showing all FF's at the beginning of drive, and ```sudo blkdid /dev/sda``` still showing ```PTTYPE="atari"```

Comment: So the disk does not return what was written. This is really critical. Can you test the disk in another PC or with another SATA/SAS controller?

Comment: Booted into an older ubuntu system and seems to be working properly. Any way to diagnose what's happening in the first system?

Comment: You might get odd results if you're running an OS residing on the disk(s) you're tampering with. Boot from a "live" disk, e.g.  Ubuntu install media, run it in "Try" mode. Also make sure to not "mount" anything from that disk. (Assuming the hardware is OK)

Comment: Probably misleading to say "booted" into, the disk isn't bootable, just for data storage.

Comment: Does lsblk confirms you in choising /dev/sda?

Comment: lsblk shows

```sda      8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   7.3T  0 part /media/billy/tk1-4```

which is the partition I created on a separate system, but is now not reading the test files in the mount point